# C++ Templates and STL vector problem

Tags: c++, templates, stl, iterator, typename

I need help in the simple matter

Im trying to create class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class merge_sort
{
protected:

    vector<T> merge(const vector<T> &a, const vector<T> &b)
    {
        vector<T> v;

        typename vector<T>::iterator A;
        A= a.begin();
        typename vector<T>::iterator B;
        B= b.begin();
...
```

but compiler gives me next error:

```
no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘A = ((const std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*)a)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::begin [with _Tp = int, _Alloc = std::allocator<int>]()’  merge.cpp   /merge_sort line 23 C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: why do you put "typename" in front of `vector<T>::iterator A;` ?

Comment: @Kiril: because `vector<T>::iterator` is a dependent name ?

Comment: And what do you get by having the typename `A` which you only use once, in the next line? Also, since this is a template class and would sit in a header - don't put any `using namespace` declarations in header files, ever.

Comment: @Mephane: template definitions sometimes belong to `.cpp` files, if the template is to be used only in this file.

Comment: @Alexandre - whoop, my bad, right. 10x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
typename vector<T>::const_iterator A = a.begin();
typename vector<T>::const_iterator B = b.begin();
```

because `a` and `b` are const references, the const version of `begin` is called, and it returns a `const_iterator`, not an `iterator`. You cannot assign `const_iterator`s to `iterator`s, like you cannot assign pointers-to-const to pointers.

Comment: @Nim you cannot assign `const_iterator`s to `iterator`s, this is like assigning a pointer to const to a pointer.

Comment: (BTW, what's wrong with `typename vector<T>::const_iterator A = a.begin();`?)

Comment: @sbi: nothing, I'd have written that in my code. But OP used assignment operator, not copy construction.

Comment: @Alexandre, I know that! :) my question was, why would you do this? another words, why would you use a non-const iterator on a const container? AHH, I see you edited the answer!!! :D okay, makes my original question seem daft!?!

Comment: @Alexandre: It was a question to the OP more than to you. I should have asked it at the question, really.

Answer (score 3):

```
typename vector<T>::iterator A;
```

Should be

```
typename vector<T>::const_iterator A;
```

Same for B

**Update**

My C++ skills are rusty, but

Because the two `vectors` passed to merge are const references, you cannot use a standard iterator to move over them, because the standard iterator allows you to modify the contents of the vector. Therefore, you must use `const_iterator`'s which will not allow you to modify the vector contents.

Apologies if my C++ Fu isn't up to scratch, I remember enough C++ to fix the problem, but haven't used C++ in anger in . . . wow 7 years (is it really that long? Bugger me but I'm getting old).

As I said, feel free to edit this answer if you can provide better explanations.

Comment: removed mine, you beat me by seconds! :)

Comment: I think `typename` here is mandatory (unless you happen to use visual studio, which is non portably laxist with `typename`)

Comment: The answer here says what you need to do. For further reference look here (esp the example as it shows a simple case on how iterators are used): http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/begin/

Comment: That should be `typename vector<T>::const_iterator`. `ector<T>::const_iterator` is clearly depending on a template parameter. (For when you doubt: Could there be, in theory, a specialization of `st::vector` for some `T` where `iterator` is the name of a static data member? If so, it needs `typename`.)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing a typedef with a decaration.

If you want to declare a typedef with a dependent type, then you do need to use the typename keyword:

```
typedef typename vector<T>::const_iterator iter
iter A = a.begin( );
iter B = b.begin( );
```

BTW, typename is required even without the typedef.